# How to get LinkedIn API OAuth token

Tags: api, linkedin-api

[image]

[image]

Using the set up above in the images, I am trying to make a rest call to LinkedIn to recieve my Oauth token following this guide: https://medium.com/@ellesmuse/how-to-get-a-linkedin-access-token-a53f9b62f0ce

However I am getting the error:
`The redirect_uri does not match the registered value`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to set up the localhost url for my callback instead of using the random google link